How to handle properly the systemd journal handle invalidation due to the log rotation
I have a journal-forwarder application running on an embedded Linux system managed by systemd. The application is similar to the example on this page: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/sd_journal_process.html. The main difference is that our application forwards logs to a backend instead of printing them.
We're encountering an issue where the application is soonly killed after a log rotation (log rotation seems to be triggered by an NTP time update). GDB indicates that the crash occurs within the systemd library. Our application uses a handle to the journal, and we suspect that this handle is invalidated due to the log rotation, but our application can't know about it and uses the invalidated handle in the sd_journal_next() API and get killed.
The main loop looks really similar to the "officially working" example:
for (;;)  
{
    r = sd_journal_next(j);
    if (r < 0) {
      LOG(ERROR) << M4S("Failed to iterate to next entry: %s") << strerror(-r); 
      break;
    }

    if (r == 0) {
      /* Reached the end, let's wait for changes, and try again */
      r = sd_journal_wait(j, (uint64_t) -1);
      if (r < 0) {
        LOG(ERROR) << M4S("Failed to wait for changes: %s") << strerror(-r); 
        break;
      }
      continue;
    }

    const void *d;
    size_t l;

    r = sd_journal_get_data(j, "MESSAGE", &d, &l);
    if (r < 0) {
      LOG(ERROR) << M4S("Failed to read message field: %s") << strerror(-r); 
      continue;
    }

    forward(std::string((const char*) d, (int) l));
}

What is the correct way to handle log rotations? I couldn't find a journald API function like is_jd_handle_valid(). How should we properly manage journal handles to avoid this issue?
here are the systemd logs:
Apr 28 17:49:36 ... old logs

Jul 10 14:19:30 systemd-timesyncd[467]: Initial synchronization to time server 216.239.35.0:123 (ntp1.com).
Jul 10 14:19:33 systemd-journald[309]: Oldest entry in /var/log/journal/000000000037001a3231511232393532/system.journal is older than the configured file reten.
Jul 10 14:19:33 systemd-journald[309]: /var/log/journal/000000000037001a3231511232393532/system.journal: Journal header limits reached or header out-of-date, r.
Jul 10 14:19:30 systemd-resolved[594]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
Jul 10 14:19:33 logrotate[821]: error: state file /var/lib/logrotate.status is world-readable and thus can be locked from other unprivileged users. Skipping lo.
Jul 10 14:19:30 systemd[1]: Starting Rotate log files...
Jul 10 14:19:31 systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 10 14:19:31 systemd[1]: Finished Rotate log files.


Jul 10 14:19:34 systemd[1]: journal-forwarder.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=7/BUS
Jul 10 14:19:34 systemd[1]: journal-forwarder.service: Failed with result 'signal'.

